# How to download csv file from pysftp to local machine? Can't get it to save on local path, or load it to a df

Tags: python, pysftp

Trying to connect to sftp, download a cvs, do some manipulation to the file and save it as a csv

I know the code is correct up to the part where it navigates to the folder in the sftp. and I think it is downloading the file because the code takes some time to run and the file that its downloading is large. But I haven't been able to execute any commands that would print the file to make sure it has actually been downloaded. Not sure if the second argument in the get function should be the target to save the file in the local computer.

```
import pysftp

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None   

myHostname = 'host.com'
myUsername = 'username'
myPassword = 'pass'

server = pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts)
server.cwd('/targetFolder/')
server.get('/targetFolder/file.csv','C:\\')
```

### this is the error I get:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-0925a6d2adf3> in <module>
     10 server = pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts)
     11 server.cwd('/targetFolder/')
---> 12 server.get('/targetFolder/file.csv','C:\\')

C:\Users\rschuetz\Documents\Winpython\WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py in get(self, remotepath, localpath, callback, preserve_mtime)
    247             sftpattrs = self._sftp.stat(remotepath)
    248 
--> 249         self._sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, callback=callback)
    250         if preserve_mtime:
    251             os.utime(localpath, (sftpattrs.st_atime, sftpattrs.st_mtime))

C:\Users\rschuetz\Documents\Winpython\WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py in get(self, remotepath, localpath, callback)
    799             Added the ``callback`` param
    800         """
--> 801         with open(localpath, "wb") as fl:
    802             size = self.getfo(remotepath, fl, callback)
    803         s = os.stat(localpath)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\'
```

Comment: Have you tried `server.get('/targetFolder/file.csv','C:\\file.csv')`? That is, the second argument should be a file name, not a directory name.

Answer (score 0):

I suspects the issue in below line and I corrected with passing second argument as raw string.

```
server.get('/targetFolder/file.csv',r'C:\\')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code is expecting a file name for local path, not a directory, so I think this will work:

```
server.get('/targetFolder/file.csv','C:/file.csv')
```